# MongoDB slow after periods of inactivity

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have created a site that uses MongoDB as the database engine and at the moment it is still under construction so it is not getting much traffic.  This means that there are periods of no requests and therefor, no queries to the database.

When I do eventually hit the site pages that use the database, MongoDB seems to take 4 or 5 seconds to come back but from that request on, it is very fast.

I can't find any information on there being a timeout or anything like that.  Is it just that the database in memory is being paged out and it takes a few seconds to page it back in?  It is running on a Windows Server 2008 VM and I am running it as a windows service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hod do you know the slowness is on mongo side? It can be your app as well.

Comment: I know that it is the MongoDB as I always go to the root page first which doesn't use the DB.  That is always quick because I have the app pool recycling and its being hit straight afterward to make sure the application is loaded.  When I then hit other non-DB pages, its fast.  Its just the first time I hit a page that uses the DB, that I get this few seconds of lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allows the OS Kernel to handle what  is kept in Memory (the current "Working Set").  Even if nothing is happening, the system will still page objects out of RAM into the page/swap, even if the RAM capacity is not being taxed.

One way around this would be to monitor for idleness and send queries in the background, or even have a background process cat the files on-disk.  This is especially helpful in pre-warming databases after startup, and likewise if your usage forms cyclical patterns.

Comment: You can also use the touch() command once every so often (the mongodb touch() command not the unix one)

Answer (score 0):

Like most styles of databases recent query results can be cached, the execution plans can be stored in some but it doesn't seem like mongodb stores query caches.

Also to improve performance make sure you implement indexes well, so you don't mistakenly create full table scans and leverage some form of index. use the explain command to see your query execution plan. (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/

**Does MongoDB handle caching?**

Yes. MongoDB keeps all of the most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.

MongoDB does not implement a query cache: MongoDB serves all queries directly from the indexes and/or data files.

Comment: One addition, the OS holds an LRU cache of data in RAM, otherwise called your working set, it isn't MongoDB that does that, it leaves all memory management up to the OS